# how select that where =list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
select NameCompany from [ParticipateFairList] 
where IdFair=(select Id from [TmpFair] where Parent_FK=88)
```

This is Correct?

how

```
For Select * From [Table] where ID=`List` or `SubQuery`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select NameCompany from [ParticipateFairList] 
where IdFair in (select Id from [TmpFair] where Parent_FK=88)
```

where IdFair in (...) instead of where IdFair =(...)

Answer (score 0):

For [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) or [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx), you want `expr IN (list | subquery)`.